# Unable to knit R markdown as instructed in the github and RStudio tutorial

Tags: github, rstudio

I am following a github tutorial on how to work with RStudio. https://resources.github.com/github-and-rstudio/

I am unable to knit the Rmd file.
This is the code I copied from the tutorial

```
---
title: "mAPS"  knit: (function(input_file, encoding) {
    out_dir <- 'docs';
    rmarkdown::render(input_file,
      encoding=encoding,
      output_file=file.path(dirname(input_file), out_dir, 'index.html'))})
output: html_document
---
```

This is the error I recieved

```
Error in yaml::yaml.load(..., eval.expr = TRUE) : 
  Parser error: while parsing a block mapping at line 1, column 1 did not find expected key at line 1, column 16
Calls: <Anonymous> ... parse_yaml_front_matter -> yaml_load -> <Anonymous>
Execution halted
```

Tried multiple ways of changing the indentation.
Did not work. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happens when you knit with a simpler YAML, and name the file "index.Rmd" e.g.

```
title: "mAPS"
output: html_document
```